# Passing function to a class

Tags: python, .net, class, ironpython

I have created a class that can take a function with a set of arguments. I would like to run the passed function every time the event handler signals.

I am attaching my code below which runs when I pass a `fun2` which has no arguments but not with `fun1`. Any suggestions that I can make to the code below work with `fun1` and `fun2`? If I omit the return statement from `fun1`, I get an error that `'str' object is not callable`.

```
>>> TimerTest.main()
function 1. this function does task1
my function from init from function1
my function in start of runTimerTraceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\TimerTest.py", line 57, in main
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\TimerTest.py", line 25, in runTime
r
TypeError: str is not callable



import System  
from System.Timers import (Timer, ElapsedEventArgs)

class timerTest:

    def __init__ (self, interval,autoreset, fun):
        self.Timer = Timer()
        self.Timer.Interval= interval
        self.Timer.AutoReset = autoreset
        self.Timer.Enabled = True
        self.myfunction = fun

    def runTimer(self):

        print 'my function in start of runTimer', self.myfunction ()

        self.Timer.Start()

        def OnTimedEvent (s, e):
                print "The Elapsed event was raised at " , e.SignalTime
                print 'printing myfunction...', self.myfunction()
                self.myfunction()

        self.Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent


    def stopTimer(self):
        self.Timer.Stop()
        self.Timer.Dispose= True


def fun1(a,b):
   print 'function 1. this function does task1'
   return 'from function1'

def fun2():
   print 'Function 2. This function does something'
   print 'Test 1...2...3...'
   return 'From function 2'

def main():
    a = timerTest(1000, True, fun1(10,20))
    a.runTimer()

    b= timerTest(3000,True,fun2)
    b.runTimer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I am learning Python and I apologize if my questions are basic.

To change the interval, I stop the timer using a stopTimer method I added to the timerTest class:

```
def stopTimer(self):
    self.Timer.Stop()
```

I take the new user input to call the runTimer method which I have revised per Paolo Moretti's suggestions:

```
def runTimer(self, interval,autoreset,fun,arg1, arg2, etc.):

    self.Timer.Interval= interval
    self.Timer.AutoReset = autoreset
    myfunction = fun
    my_args = args

    self.Timer.Start()

        def OnTimedEvent (s, e):
            print "The Elapsed event was raised at " , e.SignalTime
            myfunction(*my_args)

    self.Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent
```

Whenever a command button is pressed, the following method is called:

```
requestTimer.runTimer((self.intervalnumericUpDown.Value* 1000),True, function, *args)
```

I do not understand why stopping the timer and sending the request causes the runTimer method to be executed multiple times and it seems dependent on how many times I change the interval. I have tried  a couple of methods: Close and Dispose with no success.

A second question on slightly different subject.

I have been looking at other .NET classes with Timer classes. A second question is on how I would translate the following VB sample code into Python. Is "callback As TimerCallback" equivalent to myfunction(*my_args)?

```
Public Sub New ( _
  callback As TimerCallback, _
  state As Object, _
  dueTime As Integer, _
  period As Integer _
)
```

per .NET documentation:
callback
Type: System.Threading.TimerCallback
A TimerCallback delegate representing a method to be executed. 
I can partially get the timer event to fire if I define a function with no arguments such as:

```
def fun2(stateinfo):
    # function code
```

which works with:

```
self.Timer = Timer(fun2, self.autoEvent, self.dueTime,self.period)
```

The function call fails if I replace fun2 with a  more generic function call myfunction(*my_args)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [`*`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) syntax for calling a function with an arbitrary argument list:

```
class TimerTest:
    def __init__(self, interval, autoreset, fun, *args):
        # ...
        self.my_function = fun
        self.my_args = args
        # ...

    def run_timer(self):
        # ...
        def on_timed_event(s, e):
            # ...
            self.my_function(*self.my_args)
            # ...
```

Usage:

```
>>> t1 = TimerTest(1000, True, fun1, 10, 20)
>>> t2 = TimerTest(1000, True, fun2)
```

And check out the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide as well. Python's preferred coding conventions are different than many other common languages.

---

**Question 1**

Every time you use the addition assignment operator (`+=`) you are attaching a new event handler to the event. For example this code:

```
timer = Timer()

def on_timed_event(s, e):
    print "Hello form my event handler"

timer.Elapsed += on_timed_event
timer.Elapsed += on_timed_event

timer.Start()
```

will print the `"Hello form my event handler"`phrase twice.

For more information you can check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in particular [Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) .

So, you should probably move the event subscription to the `__init__` method, and only start the timer in your `run_timer` method:

```
def run_timer(self):
     self.Timer.Start()
```

You could also add a new method (or use a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)) for changing the interval:

```
def set_interval(self, interval):
     self.Timer.Interval = interval
```

---

**Question 2**

You are right about [`TimerCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx): it's a delegate representing a method to be executed.

For example, this [`Timer` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618.aspx):

```
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback
)
```

is expecting a `void` function with a single parameter of type `Object`.

```
public delegate void TimerCallback(
    Object state
)
```

When you are invoking a function using the `*` syntax you are doing something completely different. It's probably easier if I'll show you an example:

```
def foo(a, b, *args):
    print a
    print b
    print args

>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
1
2
(3, 4, 5)

>>> args = (1, 2, 3)
>>> foo(1, 2, *args)
1
2
(1, 2, 3)
```

Basically in the second case you are invoking a function with additional arguments unpacked from a tuple.

So If you want to pass a function with a different signature to a constructor which accepts a `TimerCallback` delegate you have to create a new function, like [@Lasse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507058/63011) is suggesting.

```
def my_func(state, a, b):
    pass
```

You can do this either using the [lambda](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) keyword:

```
t1 = Timer(lambda state: my_func(state, 1, 2))
```

or by declaring a new function:

```
def time_proc(state):
     my_func(state, 1, 2)

t2 = Timer(time_proc)
```

Comment: He's using IronPython, hence the .NET-style naming of the libraries.

Comment: @JAB The OP style is different, for example in .NET classes are declared in `CapitalizedWords` like in Python. Anyway, following the PEP8 style guide is just a suggestion :)

Comment: I am importing this code into another module. I start with an initial value of the interval and after running for awhile I stop the run_timer method and change interval in t1.  My function gets executed twice. What do I need to do to run my function once every time the interval changes?

Comment: @user2556944 Can you post some code showing your problem? You can edit your question, if you want. How are you changing the interval?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I added more detail which hopefully will explain my issue. Thanks for the reference to the style guide. I will take a look.

Comment: @CarlosBustamante I've updated my answer and retagged your question for better visibility to the ironpython community :)

Comment: Thank You for your comments they have been very helpful. Another use case I would like to consider is performing a sequence of tasks with some delay in between. Is there a recommended approach to do this? Any suggestions keywords, link to reading material is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CarlosBustamante Do you mean something like daily tasks? In Python you can use something like [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html), but I'm not sure if IronPython is supported. In .NET you can create a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to run jobs based on a configured schedule. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

If the function takes no parameters, simply pass it without calling it:

```
b = timerTest(3000, True, fun2)
```

If it takes parameters, you need to convert it to a function that doesn't take parameters. What you're doing is *calling it*, and then you pass the result, which in this case is a string. Instead do this:

```
a = timerTest(1000, True, lambda: fun1(10, 20))
```